how do I set up cloud run in a shared vpc with direct vpc egress?
In my GCP infrastructure, I have a security project (with VM as Firewall) that faces all entring and outgoing traffic to my gcp network. The security project is peered to an IT project that has a shared VPC with other projects. I have to use Cloud Run with static outbound IP, how should I configure it ?
I thought I use Direct VPC Egress to connect cloud run to the shared vpc. but I don't know if I will get a static IP for my outgoing traffic ? and does using cloud run in the same shared vpc as my GCE cause conflicts in IPs ?
thank you for your advices.

Did you set up a Cloud NAT? and route all the egress traffic to the VPC egress?

yes, I created the Cloud NAT and in Cloud Run -> networking -> Connect to a VPC for outbound traffic -> send traffic directly to a VPC -> Networks shared with me.  The error i am getting is "Access to the subnetwork is  not allowed".

my cloud run service is using the default compute engine service account. I added the role "compute network user" . Also, I created the same service account in IAM of the shared project VPC with roles : "compute network user" and "service account user". Then I disabled the policy org "cross-project service account usage" in the service project where my cloud run service run.

I could not find the service account of cloud run to add the network user role. SO
When you are under IAM, please mark little checkbox , at the middle right screen " Include Google-provided role grants".
This will show Google-managed service accounts which are used to access the APIs of Google Cloud Platform services.
